# Replace java.io.File on runtime with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

How can you replace `java.io.File` for a given web application (running on a servlet container) for the following conditions

Given I have a class `class AmazonS3File extends java.io.File`

1. Replace every `java.io.File` with `AmazonS3File`
2. Replace every `java.io.File` with `AmazonS3File` but under the condition that the call came from a specific library, say `com.jetbrains` package (not sure if this is even theoretically possible)

However, here's the *pseudo* code I have:

```
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
            .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
            .type(ElementMatchers.is(java.io.File.class))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
                    new ByteBuddy().redefine(java.io.File.class).constructor(ElementMatchers.anyOf(AmazonS3File.class) /* <-- What to put here?*/))
            .installOnByteBuddyAgent();
    File videoFile = new File(OUTPUT_PATH);
    System.out.println(videoFile.getPath());
```

What should be placed in the `ByteBuddy().redefine(java.io.File.class).constructor` to make it load the constructor of `AmazonS3File` instead?

Comment: I also understand that it's not possible to replace if the class has been loaded already as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641621/modify-java-util-class-using-byte-buddy-agent so what would be the strategy if this will be used on a Web Application where app is running on a Servlet Container (Jetty, Tomcat, NGINX Unit to name a few)

Comment: 1) why do you need to do this? 2) aspect oriented programming?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen to replace java.io.File calls by a Java library; File saves on disk, what I need is to save on Cloud storage directly and not saving to disk at all due to platform limitation.

Comment: File is an interface.  Consider making a class wrapping an AmazonS3File implementing File and pass that into the code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen `File` is a concrete class AFAIK `public class File
    implements Serializable, Comparable<File>` also the main reason for using ByteBuddy is because we can't modify the library codes (we don't maintain it)  that's why we want to just make java.io.File calls substituted at runtime, hence ByteBuddy.

Comment: Yes, I got that part wrong. Sorry. about that.  I would still look into aspect oriented programming for this.  Would a custom file system be an option - should be interoperable with File?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen changing any codes in the library is not an option for me especially since the library is so big and changing anything like that in the source code of the library--the developers most likely would not agree to have that since it is not on their use-case. So the real option is to use ByteBuddy.

Answer (score 1):

Byte Buddy allows you to adjust library code by for example using a Java agent. A Java agent is notified on any class being loaded and using one, you can indeed replace any call to `new File()` by your `new AmazonS3File()`. To do so, you would need to transform all classes within a package where this in-code replacement is relevant. You would be using a `MemberSubstitution` for this:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
        .type(nameStartsWith("pkg.of.library."))
        .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder.visit(MemberSubstitution.strict()
             .constructor(isDeclaredBy(File.class))
             .replaceWith(MyFactory.class.getMethod("file", String.class))
             .on(any()))
        .installOnByteBuddyAgent();
```

To make this work, you will have to create some factory class `MyFactory` that returns any instance of type `File` where you can for example return your Amazon file if it exteds Java's `File`.

The substitution basically says: for any type in the package and subpackages of *pgk.of.library*, scan `any()` method or constructor for constructors of `File` and replace them with a call to `MyFactory::file`. For this to work, the factory must have the same arguments as the file constructor being replaced.